# How can I include secrets to my docker image?

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, dockerfile

I've built myself a web api that uses a sql database. I've used Visual Studio to create this project, and have the ability to right click and "manage user secrets" on my project file.

Its in user secrets that I've stored my connection string and I dont want to add it to my github (private) repo.
The user secret is a json file.

How do I noe include these secrets? Do I include them in the project, making them a part of the image? Or do I do something fancy with the running instance?

Comment: No, you should not include them in your image but only in the running container. The best ist probably referencing to those secrets via environment variables and setting those environment variables when you start that container.

Comment: This blog post suggests [bind-mounting the secrets into the container](https://jimmybogard.com/user-secrets-in-docker-based-net-core-worker-applications/).

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to go about doing this, but typically you either:

1. Extract your secrets from your codebase (GIT repo), inject them through environment variables at container startup and then access them from your application code like any other environment var. This is not the *most* secure option, but at least your secrets won't be in your VCS anymore.
2. Pull the secrets from some type of secrets manager (e.g. [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/)) straight from your application code. This is *more* secure than the first option, but requires more code changes and creates a dependency between your application and your secrets manager.